# Is JBoss EAP 7 has a functionality that Wildfly doesn't have?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, redhat, application-server

I'm going to install WildFly because it's open source and it's free compared to Jboss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss EAP 7 is based on WildFly Application Server. WildFly is the community project whereas JBoss EAP is highly integerated, tested and certified enterprise platform which includes patches, updates,support contract, and maintenance policies.

Comment: can you give me some links that states that one?

Comment: See link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WildFly

Comment: You can also see http://wildfly.org/governance/. https://developers.redhat.com/products/eap/download/ or https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/jboss-middleware/application-platform