# Is it fine to use WildFly 10 instead of JBOSS EAP 7? If so, is WildFly 10 stable?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10, application-server, jboss-eap-7

I want to use JBOSS EAP 7 but it has subscription charges so I changed my mind to use WildFly 10. Also, I want to know if all the functionalities of WildFly 10 works well just like JBOSS EAP 7. Anyone can give me some ideas?

Comment: WildFly 11.0.0.Final is out now too. http://wildfly.org/downloads

Answer (score 1):

Please check [Is JBoss EAP 7 has a functionality that Wildfly doesn't have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952373/is-jboss-eap-7-has-a-functionality-that-wildfly-doesnt-have) and links https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/jboss-middleware/application-platform, https://developers.redhat.com/products/eap/download/ .